Async API description only with global components using Quarkus Async API Extensions
I'm using as example a AMQP quickstart project from Quarkus Github:https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/amqp-quickstart
and already added Async API extensions according to the page: https://quarkus.io/extensions/io.quarkiverse.asyncapi/quarkus-asyncapi/
I see an endpoint to download an Async API description but it seems that scanner did not find Channel annotations in the code, but there are. As output there are only global component hardcoded in:
https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-asyncapi/blob/61e642d0bebd08b661bf4c5dc90832bd648ddc63/quarkus-asyncapi-scanner/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkiverse/asyncapi/annotation/scanner/AsyncApiAnnotationScanner.java
I have class with Channel annotation in the index.
Do I need to create some config? Or do something with index?
